# Flutter iOS Style Grid Pinching Animation

Tags: ios, flutter

How can one make a dynamic GridView.builder using Flutter where the user can zoom in and out to change the number of columns of the grid such as the iOS Photo Gallery app.

[image]

Comment: any method you found?